# Incremental backup perl crontab

Tags: perl, backup

I would like to write a perl program to make an incremental backup of my server.

It should be something like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use File::Copy;
use File::Rotate::Backup;
use File::Path;

    rmtree "/backup/";
    mkdir "/backup";

    my $file= { archive_copies => 1,
            dir_copies => 1,
            backup_dir => '/backup',
            file_prefix => 'backup_' ,
            verbose => 1,
            use_flock =>1,
            };

    my $copy= File::Rotate::Backup->new($file);
    $copy->backup([[ '/home/' => 'home' ] ]);
```

like this, Im just creating each time I execute a new folder with the backup, but I would like to have a folder with a full backup of the first day and the incremental of the rest of the week.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: May be the solution already exists: rsnapshot [link] (http://rsnapshot.org/). It is written in perl. Consider to use it.